# Not able to connect Oracle container database from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am not able to connect the docker container using SQL developer. I used the docker desktop container internal ip ( ip a) and port number (docker port <container_name> ), but still getting the below error.

Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=nEnUfwk5Spaz8T7qS3vmCw==)

Here is my SQL Developer configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ip address and port aren't reachable from your host machine where SQL Developer is running.

See here where our Docker images are setup for you to simply connect via localhost:
https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe